# I can't get a class to work

Tags: perl, class

I want to create a Perl class.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/ bin/perl

package Data;

sub new
{ my ($class, $student) = @_;
$class = shift;
$student = shift;
$student = {_firstName => <>,
            _lastName => <>,
             _matric => <>,
            };
bless $student,$class;
print $student;
}
&new;
```

And I got this error:

> main=HASH(0x215fc40)Use of uninitialized value $class in bless at source_file.pl line 12.
>   Explicit blessing to '' (assuming package main) at source_file.pl line 12.

---

I use dcoder and I don't think it supports separating the program. But though I corrected it but it still leaves no output. I tried to print `$self` but it left an error. Here's the entire code:

```
#!/usr/ bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

package student;

sub new {
 my $class = shift;
    my ($first, $last, $matric) = @_;
    my $self = {
        _firstName => $first,
        _lastName => $last,
        _matric => $matric,
        };
    bless $self, $class;
    }

my $self = student->new('victor','valdes','csc');
print $self;
```

And here's the error:

> student=HASH(0x238ae98)

I'm sorry I'm really new at this and still don't understand.

Comment: That's working fine. `student=HASH(0x238ae98)` says that you have a `student` object formed from a hash at address `0x238ae98`. You need to *do a lot more reading*.

Answer (score 5):

This looks very much like a homework question, so I'm hesitating to give you a complete answer. You appear to have very little knowledge of Perl, and have made little effort to read about Perl's object-oriented ideas, using wild guesses to fill the gaps. You're not going to learn the language that way

You should *never* call a Perl subroutine using an ampersand, and *methods* need to be called on a class or object, so `&new` should be `Data->new(...)`. Also every Perl source file you write should begin with `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`

That's a very odd way of creating an object. You would ordinarily create a separate Perl program that does `use Data` and then `my $object = Data->new($student)`. Instead you are calling `&new`, which passes no parameters and is the reason for your *uninitialized value* error

It isn't at all obvious what your `$student` value is supposed to be, but after using `shift` to get its value from `@_` you then overwrite it with a hash reference

You should also be passing values for the hash contents via the `new` constructor call, rather than getting the module itself to read from `STDIN`. You also fail to `chomp` those values so that they will retain their terminating newlines, which you're unlikely to want

I suggest that you separate your code into `Data.pm` (perhaps `Student.pm`?) and `main.pl` and start by writing the code using constant values instead of reading from the keyboard

Something like this

#### Student.pm

```
package Student;

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my ($first, $last, $matric) = @_;

    my $self = {
        _firstName => $first,
        _lastName  => $last,
        _matric    => $matric,
    };

    bless $self, $class;
}

1;
```

#### main.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Student;

my $student =  Student->new('John', 'Smith', 1987);
```

Comment: Please don't start the keys of the hash with underscores. The conventions are: no prefix for data elements; a minus sign for options (if any); and a space for those things only the brave or foolish should modify. 

Comment: I've been using POerl since version 4. It's weird code (not books) where I have seen this.

Answer (score 3):

If you're insisting on keeping all of the code in a single file, then you should at least move the "non-class" code into a separate package.

```
#!/usr/ bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

# Capital letters for user-defined packages, please
package Student;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my ($first, $last, $matric) = @_;
    my $self = {
        _firstName => $first,
        _lastName => $last,
        _matric => $matric,
    };
    bless $self, $class;
}

package main;

# $self is only used as a variable name within methods.
my $student = Student->new('victor','valdes','csc');
print $student;
```

But that's just good practice, it isn't really affecting anything in your code. You say you get this output:

> student=HASH(0x238ae98)

You describe it as an error, but it's not an error at all That's exactly what I'd expect from your code. Your `$self` variable (which I've renamed as `$student`) is a blessed hash reference. And that's what you get if you print a blessed hash reference.

But if you want to see more of the structure of your object, you can use Data::Dumper (a standard Perl library).

```
package main;

use Data::Dumper;

# $self is only used as a variable name within methods.
my $student = Student->new('victor','valdes','csc');
print Dumper $student;
```

That gives me:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 '_lastName' => 'valdes',
                 '_firstName' => 'victor',
                 '_matric' => 'csc'
               }, 'Student' );
```

It's not clear to me what you expected your `print()` statement to produce. But if you want to display attributes from your object, then you need to write accessor methods inside your class. For example, a method to return the matric value would look like this:

```
sub matric {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{_matric};
}
```

And in the main package you would call it like this:

```
print $student->matric;
```

But I have to agree with Borodin. It very much looks like you're trying to teach yourself object oriented programming in Perl without knowing much about either object oriented programming or Perl. And guessing at concepts and syntax is rarely a successful approach.

I'll also add that the "classic" style of Perl OO that you're using has been largely superseded by modern OO frameworks like [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo). You might have more success using that.